# extracting digits using regex in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am new to regex and still trying to wrap my head around it. I am stuck at this one point and all related questions to my problem doesnt seem to help.

I have a text varible

```
set text "/folders/beta_0_2_1"
```

I want to extract 0, 2, 1 and save them in three different variables using regex in tcl.
I tried to reach through beta variable using

```
[regexp {/beta_} $text]
```

However, I am not able to figure out the part where I can extract each of those variables and then save them. Can you provide me some direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
regexp {/beta_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)} $text -> num1 num2 num3
```

Then you can use the variables:

```
puts "$num1 $num2 $num3"
# => 0 2 1
```

`->` by the way is a convention. This variable (yes, it's one!) will contain the whole match.

---

And as a side note, you could also split it by underscore:

```
lassign [split $text "_"] - num1 num2 num3

puts "$num1 $num2 $num3"
# => 0 2 1
```

Comment: @UnderDog Yup! It's used with lists and was [introduced in Tcl 8.5](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1530).

Answer (score 3):

to extract all the sequences of digits:

```
% set text "/folders/beta_0_2_1"
/folders/beta_0_2_1
% regexp -inline -all {\d+} $text
0 2 1
% lassign [regexp -inline -all {\d+} $text] a b c
% puts $a; puts $b; puts $c
0
2
1
```